# Update MYSQL Rows Created by Html input array? [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using HTML input arrays to give the user the option to add more input fields with javascript.

It looks like this: `<input name="[services]" ..../>`
So as long as there are values in [services] my php script is creating rows into database table "Services". Every Service beolongs to one Invoice so always a few of them sahre the same "InvoiceID" in the table.

Now I want to provide the possibility to edit those services. I see no problem to output those rows but how to use the UPDATE function here? 
I have to update every row with the sane Invoice ID and checking the individual serviceID aswell, since there are a lot of "Services" from different invoices in the database.

Has anyone an idea?

kind regards,
Marvin

Comment: You should provide code which reproduces your problem or show any even failed progress in solving your problem.

Comment: *"how to use the UPDATE function here? "* => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: There is no code describing my problem. I have none . So thats why i describe my problem with words. I just need a start :)

Answer (score -1):

In this case I fixed it by just deleting the existing rows with the same invoiceID and saved the new items afterwards.